# How to extend Tabulator with resizable column plugin

Tags: tabulator

I thought this would be shown in the docs but I'm trying to get column resizing working with [Tabulator](https://tabulator.info).

[This page](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/modules#module-resizeTable) just describes how to import the plugin:

```js
import {ResizeTableModule} from 'tabulator-tables';
```

But what do you with this import? I thought you could add it to `Tabulator.extendModule(ResizeTableModule)` but that does nothing. I couldn't find any examples using plugins modularly like this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get column resizing working, you can import `ResizeColumnsModule` as follows:

```js
import { Tabulator, ResizeColumnsModule } from "tabulator-tables";

Tabulator.registerModule(ResizeColumnsModule)
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-wescoff-nw337l?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score -1):

As per docs correct way to extend a module is like

```
/**
 * @param {String} moduleName
 * @param {any} configs
 * @param {any} newconfig
 */
Tabulator.extendModule("resizeTable", "config", {
    //Your New Config
    name: "__int__",
});
```

I am afriad as `ResizeTableModule` module does not expose any other config but you can define them by extending the class

```
import { Tabulator, ResizeColumnsModule, ResizeTableModule } from "tabulator-tables";

class MyResizeTableModule extends ResizeTableModule {
    constructor(table) {
        super(table);

        this.config = MyResizeTableModule.config;
    }
}

MyResizeTableModule.config = {};

Tabulator.registerModule([MyResizeTableModule, ResizeColumnsModule]);

/**
 * @param {String} moduleName
 * @param {any} configs
 * @param {any} newconfig
 */
Tabulator.extendModule("resizeTable", "config", {
    //Your New Config
    name: "__int__",
});
```

See [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-water-k6p2u0?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: He is asking how to register the resize module, not how to extend an existing module